# Exhibit at the museum

Tags: riddle

A museum is hosting a special exhibit.  Five items from the exhibit are on display at the museum's entrance, each with a plaque describing them.

Plaque 1:

```
In original making I needed the light,
my final formation is black as the night.
Ancient creation, of wood under sea -
what can this strange mystery be?
```

Plaque 2:

```
Of rainbow hue, though often gold,
an ancient tale, rarely told.
Formed of wood both thick and thin,
a hidden secret lies within.
```

Plaque 3:

```
Though not plants, we tiny flowers
lies within our watery bowers.
Though individually each is small,
yet walls we build exceeding tall.
```

Plaque 4:

```
Come on down to the old pool hall -
You'll have a good time, I'll have a real ball.
They say I have value, but to tell you the truth
I'm really just part of a rather large tooth.
```

Plaque 5:

```
Though saved for the last I'm by no means the least,
great riches I yield unto those in the East.
Strange it may sound, strange it may be,
my mother, in fact, was named after me!
```

**Based on these displays, what is the theme of this special exhibit?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The theme is:

> organic gems.

The objects on display are:

> jet - produced from wood decaying under water and high pressure
> amber - fossilized tree resin, sometimes contains trapped insects or other things
> coral - produced by colonies of coral polyps, which are from the animal kingdom
> ivory - derived from elephant tusks and used to make pool balls
> pearl - "mother of pearl" is inside pearl oysters

Comment: Is that where the phrase "jet black" comes from?!?! (°Д°)

Comment: @feelinferrety Yeah, it literally means as black as jet.